# Why Assignment in python does not copy objects.What are Various scenarios where objects get binded instead of getting copied?

Tags: python, copy

while using python in my project I found that when assigning object A to B it was creating a binding instead of copying
Also it would be a great help if reflected all the scenarios like (passing object as a parameter to a function), where we should be cautious of properly copying instead of just ending up creating a binding.

Comment: Basic types likes ints, floats or strings are copied, everything else is passed by reference.

Comment: nope: everything is a reference. it's just that immutable objects see their reference change when they're modified.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, what about tuples then?

Comment: @Rawing: *"Basic types likes ints, floats or strings are copied"* Can you provide a reference or an example?

Comment: I know what I said isn't technically correct, but I think it's a good explanation for OP to understand.

Comment: @Rawing sorry, but why would anyone want misleading explanation?

Comment: @vaultah An easy to understand but slightly incorrect answer can be better than a 100% accurate but confusing answer. It's a question of how much experience OP has with programming. You can add a technically correct answer if you like, then OP can ignore the less useful one.

Answer (score 0):

A and B are names that refer to objects, not the objects themselves. So lets say x is actually an object (in python, the object id will be many characters longer but for demonstrative purposes let's shorten to x). If the value of x is 5, and A is a name that points to x, then printing A will print 5, and passing A as an argument will pass 5. If you decide to code B=A, you aren't setting B equal to A, you're setting B equal to the object (x) that A refers. So, even if you subsequently code A=y (with y being an object), B will still point to X.

This is all covered in the docs on python.org.